# Animating windshield wipers along curved glass

Tags: modifiers, armature

[image: Wipers down (aligned, everything is fine)][image: Wipers up, wipers are off compared to arm]So I have a couple wipers on the front of my car that I'm trying to have animated. I have an armature moving both the arm of the wiper and the blade itself. I'm using a surface deform modifier to stick the wiper to the windshield. I'm having a problem where the wiper blade doesn't line up with the arm correctly.

Comment: Could you add some pictures to your question? Please show us your setup and settings used, it is hard to follow what you are saying

Comment: Is it only the viewport that is out of sync? Some dependencies can get out of sync in the viewport but show fine in render. Are the wiper arm and blade using the same bone? What modifier order do you have? Start blender from a terminal and add the `--enable-new-depsgraph` option and see if that offers an improvment.

Comment: Duarte, I hope the images I provided help.